# Markdown italics bug

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

On [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42661696/1255289) I used this markdown: `*x*2, *x*6, *x*A, *x*E` expecting the x to be italicised, but this only happened for the last two items:

*x*2 *x*6 *x*A *x*E

This appears to be triggered only by one or more following digit:

```
*foo*bar *foo*42
```

*foo*bar *foo*42

Looks like the same thing happens globally!

Comment: A workaround would be to use `<i>`: `<i>foo</i>42`. I edited your answer accordingly.